# How to run the same test-case for different classes?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have several classes that share some invariants and have a common interface, and I would like to run automatically the same test for each of them.

As an example, suppose I have several classes that implement different approaches for partitioning a data-set. The common invariant here would be, that for all of these classes the union over all partitions should equal the original data-set.

What I currently have looks something like this:

```
class PartitionerInvariantsTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testDataSet = range(100) # create test-data-set

    def impl(self, partitioner):
        self.assertEqual(self.testDataSet, 
                         chain.from_iterable(partitioner(self.testDataSet))
```

Then I add a different function that calls `impl` for each of the classes I want to test with an instance of that class. The problem with this becomes apparent when doing this for more than one test-function. Suppose I have 5 test-functions and 5 classes I want to test. This would make 25 functions that look almost identical for invoking all the tests.

Another approach I was thinking about was to implement the template as a super-class, and then create a sub-class for each of the classes I want to test. The sub-classes could provide a function for instantiating the class. The problem with that is that the default test-loader would consider the (unusable) base-class a valid test-case and try to run it, which would fail.

So, what are your suggestions?

P.S.: I am using Python 2.6

Comment: Will unittest try to run the base class if it doesn't inherit from `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: @Nathon: Now that you say it, I have not tried that yet.

Comment: @Nathon, if you'd like to post your idea as an answer, I'll happily delete mine.

Comment: @unutbu, no worries; I don't know my way around Python's unittest module and kevpie's answer is pretty much what I would have said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use multiple inheritance.

```
class PartitionerInvariantsFixture(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testDataSet = range(100) # create test-data-set
        super(PartitionInvariantsFixture, self).setUp()

    def test_partitioner(self):
        TestCase.assertEqual(self.testDataSet, 
                     chain.from_iterable(self.partitioner(self.testDataSet))

class MyClassTests(TestCase, PartitionerInvariantsFixture):
    partitioner = Partitioner
```

Comment: chain iterator should likely be iterated using list(chain...)

Comment: why do we need to call super in setup?

Comment: +1 My jaw is dropped. There are dozens of similar questions on SO (running the same tests on different objects with core unittest), but this is definitely the best answer I've found. I didn't even know (or didn't remember) that Python had multiple inheritance.

Comment: I tried to create a simple example using this template, it looks like setUp is never called.

Comment: @eric.frederich would you be willing to post your sample as a question and link to it from here so I can take a look?

Comment: The standard library `unittest.TestCase` calls `super()` in none of its (empty) methods like `setUp`. This means that in some configurations (depending on the method resolution order, which can be checked with `__mro__`) you won't call _all_ the `setUp`s. You can monkey-patch the standard library, but that is A Bad Idea. I have previously solved this problem without multiple inheritance but with an `abstractTCase` decorator instead, which checked class IDs at runtime to decide whether or not to run the method when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `PartitionerInvariantsTests`:

```
class PartitionerInvariantsTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_impl(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.testDataSet, 
                         chain.from_iterable(self.partitioner(self.testDataSet))

class PartitionerATests(PartitionerInvariantsTests):
```

for each Partitioner class you wish to test. Then `test_impl` would be run for each Partitioner class, by virtue of inheritance.

Following up on Nathon's comment, you can prevent the base class from being tested by having it inherit only from `object`:

```
import unittest

class Test(object):
    def test_impl(self):
        print('Hi')

class TestA(Test,unittest.TestCase):
    pass

class TestB(Test,unittest.TestCase):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.sys.argv.insert(1,'--verbose')
    unittest.main(argv = unittest.sys.argv)
```

Running test.py yields

```
test_impl (__main__.TestA) ... Hi
ok
test_impl (__main__.TestB) ... Hi
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Yes, but the base-class will also be run, and fail. Is there any way to run the subclasses, but not the base-class?