# How to run the same test for different class?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test (unittest.TestCase) and I want to test more different implementation of a class with the same interface.

The max that I have do it's something like this:

```
def create_test(class_to_test):
    class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.class_to_test = class_to_test
            self.class_to_test.two = 2
        def test_2(self):
            self.assertEqual(self.claa_to_test.two, 2)

    return TestClass

test = [create_test(x) for x in classes_to_test]
```

But I want just a bit more, I want that the definition of the class is in a different file and not into the function, and that the test was more standard as possible (the test should be "normal" as another one normal test).

I've just seen [How to run the same test-case for different classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316294/how-to-run-the-same-test-case-for-different-classes/)...

EDIT: I know the name of the class to test only at run-time...
(it'a a important particular)

I'm italian so my english isn't perfect, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can subclass unittests:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.a = 10

class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
      A.__init__(self)
      self.b = 50

class A_Test(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.test_obj = A()

   def test_A(self):
      self.assertEqual(self.test_obj.a, 10)

class B_Test(A_Test):
   def setUp(self):
      self.test_obj = B()

   def test_B(self):
      self.assertEqual(self.test_obj.b, 50)
```

`test_A` is inherited in B_Test, so this test will be run within the class on your (A-inherited) B object.

Comment: I did exactly this for some image processing stuff. My base class tests all the operations you'd do on an image and have derived classes for each type of input image I need to process. That way all kinds of input data have all the same tests applied to them without any extra work on my part. Add a new image type? Insert two lines into the unit test module and now it's fully covered.

Comment: Uhmm, no, but it's my error.
I know the name of the class to test only a run-time...

Comment: "I know the name of the class to test only a run-time.."?  You're kidding, right?  You know all the names of all your classes.  A "run-time configuration" is one thing.  Test that.  Each individual class that can be configured are separate things.  Test them separately.  Testing the "integration" of a configuration and a bunch of classes isn't really unit testing any longer.

Comment: No, I don't kidding...
I want to test different class from different development which the same goal (the test).
I have N test, who build a class that pass all "win". It's so crazy?

Comment: @Siscia, You've somewhat defied the definition of "unit" testing here. I know you're trying to create a convenient method for testing classes that you may or may not know about yet, but the essence of unit testing is knowing exactly how your individual class is supposed to act and test that. Designing your classes based on a common unit test might not be the best approach. Please reconsider.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know that isn't the good way to development, but it isn't for my use... 
I hope than someone could help me... 
Thanks Everybody